# watir switch between drivers

Tags: ruby, watir

I created multiple browsers and I'm in need to switch between them however when I go the conventional way I get this error message.which is like this

```
browser[i].button(:name=>'submit').click
```

the error that pops up:-

```
Browsing context has been discarded (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
```

which made me think that I need to switch between browser[0] and browser[1] however switch to is not defined for a browser. any ideas?

```
browser[i].switch_to.window(browser[(i+1)%z].window_handle)
```

Comment: What is `browser` in this context?

Comment: browser[i]=Watir::Browser.new :firefox,profile: profile

Comment: You can only switch to windows opened in the same driver session. Each Watir::Browser instance has a different driver session.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly why I used a different driver. then why browser[i].button(:name=>'submit').click raise that exception?

Comment: Are you closing browser windows or tabs somewhere?

Comment: nope i'm only working with these browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect with two different browser which has been opened by two different  driver,  you can shift between browser which has been opened by one single driver. For an example when you click a link if it opens a new window then you can shift to the new window.

You can shift to the new window by writing the following code

```
 b.windows.last.use do |browser|
       browser.button.click #for an example
 end
```

Comment: doesn't this switch between only two windows?

Comment: I'm thinking about runing the script multple times with different variables if it was not by anychance possible for me to do this through one script. i will just let a script generate the others and each script will control it's browser.

Comment: @Syched Flow You can obviously run in multiple windows but you can't switch between windows.